# What can I create a roadgrid from code, using the OpenStreetMaps.org data?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson, react-leaflet

Currently I am trying to create a Map from the OSM data which is openly available to create road links, using Data that I retrieved from GeoJSON.io

[image: This is the map]

The map I got from coordinates at OSM and the Blue links on the roads I created using http://geojson.io/  where I manually drew the roads on the map. I used the GeoJson Component on React-leaflet to display the road data which I got manually. Is there a way to do this road drawing automatically? I had done this mainly so that I can pass events to onclick/onhover/etc onto each road segment.

Comment: Start by reading https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data and https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles

Comment: Take a look at Overpass API. There are Leaflet plugins for Overpass API available.